# How to attach external script to existing Visual studio project

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

Attaching existing .cs file to windows forms application project

Comment: One way - drop copy of your **cs** file into location you wish in your project directory. Then, in solution explorer click `show all files` and you will see now your file in solution explorer. Right -click this file and click on `include in project`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click on solution explorer.

Right click on project name, Add -> existing item.

Select the script you want to add.

In Form1.cs file mention following

```
using Namespace_of_attached_cs_file
```